# Code's improvement (plots animation) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, animation, plot

My intention is creating an animated plot which will represent the trajectory of a body in the space. I have written this code for it. My problem is more simple that it appears. I want to see the movie (the animated plot stored) in the active figure window but I can not. When I maximize the window, I realize it is empty i.e. the movie is not contained.

```
t = 0:pi/50:10*pi;
x = sin(t);
y = cos(t);
z = t;
xmin = min(x);
ymin = min(y);
zmin = min(z);
xmax = max(x);
ymax = max(y);
zmax = max(z);
fh = figure;
ah = axes('Parent',fh);
N = 101;

for i = uint8(1):uint8(N+1)
    delta = (10*pi)/N;
    b = delta*(double(i-1));
    t = 0:0.01:b;
    plot3(ah,sin(t),cos(t),t);
    set(ah, 'XLim', [xmin xmax],'YLim', [ymin ymax],'Zlim',[zmin zmax]);
    axis square;
    pause(0.008);
    M(i) = getframe(ah);
end

cla;
movie(ah,M,1);
```

---

It is my fault. All is Ok. I had not understand well how to work movie command. Thank you for all comments about it.

Comment: Downvoters should explain their rationale, and be extra patient with new SO members.

Comment: @Jim Ferrans: Thank you so much for your comment. I am sharing my code with the community and perhaps it will be useful for someone in the future. There is no bad intention for my part.

Comment: The code seems to work for me, so I don't understand your exact problem. `getframe()` captures an image of the current axis, therefore you can't change the resolution afterwards. If you want the movie fullscreen, you have to plot it fullscreen the first time and capture that.

Comment: otherwise you might be looking at something like `comet3(sin(t),cos(t),t)`

Comment: @groovingandi: Thanks for your comment. It seems to be the one possible solution.

Comment: @Juhl: Thank you for your response. I could use that function but I would need to custom some features for my purpose.